# Does DataStax Enterprise Graph support Directed Acyclic Graphs?

Tags: datastax-enterprise, datastax-enterprise-graph

Does [DataStax Enterprise Graph](http://www.datastax.com/products/datastax-enterprise-graph) support directed acyclic graphs (DAGs)? I have searched but cannot find confirmation. My assumption is yes.

If so, what limitations around the graph structure are there?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, DES Graph supports the DAG implementation.  It is the responsibility of the developer to ensure edges are properly established to meet the DAG requirements of the Graph. DSE Graph does not support any features to enforce acyclicness.